# rmw_implementation dependency on rmw_opensplice_cpp

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I just upgraded to Dashing and ran into [this issue](https://github.com/ros2/rosidl_typesupport_opensplice/issues/30) when compiling control_msgs. As a workaround, I wanted to just uninstall the current openslice packages but there appears to be a required dependency chain that won't let it uninstall.

`rclcpp` -> `rmw_implementation` -> `rmw_opensplice_cpp` -> `rosidl_typesupport_opensplice_cpp`

I would not have expected `rmw_implementation` to depend on `rmw_opensplice_cpp` here (or `rmw_fastrtps_cpp`). Is this intended? Note, for example, that `rosidl_typesupport_cpp` only suggests `rosidl_typesupport_opensplice_cpp`, which is what I would expect.

(side note: "dashing" needs to be added to the ROS answers distribution tag list)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324757/rmw_implementation-dependency-on-rmw_opensplice_cpp/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2019-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're seeing [this issue](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/rmw_implementation-release/issues/1), and the fix [is in the process of being released](https://github.com/ros2-gbp/rmw_implementation-release/issues/1#issuecomment-498419498).

The opensplice packages can be [temporarily removed using dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17745/how-to-remove-a-deb-without-removing-its-dependencies).

`sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends ros-dashing-rmw-opensplice-cpp ros-dashing-rosidl-typesupport-opensplice-cpp ros-dashing-rosidl-typesupport-opensplice-c`

Before you upgrade or install other packages you'll want to reinstall the opensplice packages that were force uninstalled using

`sudo apt-get install --fix-broken`

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2019-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2019-06-05**:
Thanks! Glad to hear everything is under control.